# Error de sintaxis de PHP7 con PHP8

Tags: php7, apache2, php8

Estoy trabajando con PHP8 con Ubuntu/Apache2 y tengo un error de sintaxis con las propiedades tipadas que se incorporaron en PHP 7.4, es decir, que con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private string $name = 'Foo';


    public function printName()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->printName();
```

Obtengo un error en la línea: `private string $name = 'Foo';`. En los logs de error de *Apache2*:

> [Sat Aug 07 16:53:34.181584 2021] [php7:error] [pid 1493] [client
> ::1:47842] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'string'
> $(T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in
> /var/www/html/PHP/TestTypedProperties.php on line 5, referer:
> http:/$http://localhost/PHP/pruebas/

---

En la terminal, la version de PHP:

```
php --version
```

> PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 13:03:21) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Con la función `phpinfo()` en un fichero PHP, sin embargo, obtengo: `PHP Version 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`.

---

Tengo versiones anteriores instaladas de PHP, el comando:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

Muestra:

```
Existen 4 opciones para la alternativa php (que provee /usr/bin/php).

  Selección   Ruta             Prioridad  Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        modo automático
  1            /usr/bin/hhvm     40        modo manual
  2            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        modo manual
  3            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        modo manual
* 4            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        modo manual
```

Y mi lista de módulos PHP instalados:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php
```

> libapache2-mod-php7.2                           install
> libapache2-mod-php7.4                           install
> libapache2-mod-php8.0                           install php
> install php-bz2                                         install
> php-common                                      install php-curl
> install php-dev                                         install php-gd
> install php-imagick                                     install
> php-mbstring                                    install php-mysql
> install php-pear                                        install
> php-php-gettext                                 install php-phpseclib
> install php-sqlite3                                     install
> php-tcpdf                                       install php-xml
> install php-zip                                         install
> php5.6-common                                   install php5.6-imagick
> install php7.0-common                                   install
> php7.0-imagick                                  install php7.1-common
> install php7.1-imagick                                  install php7.2
> install php7.2-bz2                                      install
> php7.2-cli                                      install php7.2-common
> install php7.2-curl                                     install
> php7.2-gd                                       install php7.2-imagick
> install php7.2-json                                     install
> php7.2-mbstring                                 install php7.2-mysql
> install php7.2-opcache                                  install
> php7.2-readline                                 install php7.2-sqlite3
> deinstall php7.2-xml                                      install
> php7.2-zip                                      install php7.3-common
> install php7.3-imagick                                  install php7.4
> install php7.4-bz2                                      install
> php7.4-cli                                      install php7.4-common
> install php7.4-curl                                     install
> php7.4-dev                                      install php7.4-gd
> install php7.4-imagick                                  install
> php7.4-imap                                     install php7.4-intl
> install php7.4-json                                     install
> php7.4-mbstring                                 install php7.4-mysql
> install php7.4-opcache                                  install
> php7.4-readline                                 install php7.4-sqlite3
> deinstall php7.4-xml                                      install
> php7.4-xmlrpc                                   install php7.4-zip
> install php8.0                                          install
> php8.0-bz2                                      install php8.0-cli
> install php8.0-common                                   install
> php8.0-curl                                     install php8.0-dev
> install php8.0-gd                                       install
> php8.0-imagick                                  install
> php8.0-mbstring                                 install php8.0-mysql
> install php8.0-opcache                                  install
> php8.0-readline                                 install php8.0-sqlite3
> install php8.0-xml                                      install
> php8.0-zip                                      install phpmyadmin
> install pkg-php-tools                                   install

> Editado
> He seleccionado PHP7.4 y reiniciado Apache y mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Al usar `sudo update-alternatives --config php` se modifica la ***versión de cli PHP***, es decir la versión de PHP de la terminal.

Además de lo anterior, si se va a usar una versión diferente en las aplicaciones, hay que cargar el módulo PHP deseado en *Apache*.

**Paso a paso**

1. Deshabilitar el módulo PHP en uso, *el que indica `phpinfo()` si se usa en un fichero PHP.*

   sudo a2dismod php7.2
2. Cargar el módulo de PHP deseado, *por ejemplo, para PHP8:*

   sudo a2enmod php8.0
3. Reiniciar Apache2:

   systemctl restart apache2

Ahora, al cargar el fichero PHP con `phpinfo()` aparece la versión esperada de PHP:

```
PHP Version 8.0.9
```

La salución viene de: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Intenta colocar

```
    <?php

class Foo
{
    private (string) $name = 'Foo'; // En paréntesis el decorador del tipo de variable.


    public function printName()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->printName();
```

Mejores ejemplos acerca de la declaración de tipos puedes encontrar en el enlace a continuación:

[Type Casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Comment: Aunque si el OP configura correctamente que versión usará entonces puede emplear la primera sintaxis